# Google reCaptcha always resetting with laravel 5.1

Tags: validation, laravel-5, recaptcha

I've searched about it on internet but it seems to be different. I'm using `laravel5.1` and implemented `google recaptcha`. The scenario is, if the form was submitted and returns the validation with error, the recaptcha is resetting again and again, what I want is to not to reset it again, just staying as validated, because it annoys users to validate again and again. Do you have any idea about this?

**Update:** *for code*

```
public function postRegister(Request $request){
    // Validation
    $this->validate($request, [
        'username' => 'required|unique:users|max:20|min:3',
        'password' => 'required|min:6',
        'retype_password' => 'required|same:password',
        'email' => 'required|unique:users|email|max:255',
        'g-recaptcha-response' => 'required|recaptcha'
    ]);

    // Database save part here...

    return redirect()->route('register')->with('info', 'Success!');
}
```

Comment: Could you not validate the captcha, if valid, set a session variable to not require it again, and remove it from your form?

Comment: Hi. Can you answer it with more details? It's a little bit confusing.

Comment: Can you post some code, then I have something to work with.

Comment: Great. Please see the update.

Comment: I've put together an example of what I was suggesting. This could likely be streamlined further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a little more verbose now that I am trying to write the code, but you get the gist.

Validate your Recaptcha field first. If it is valid, set a session variable to prevent it being rendered in your form again.

```
public function postRegister(Request $request)
{
    // Prepare validation rules
    $defaultRules = [
        'username' => 'required|unique:users|max:20|min:3',
        'password' => 'required|min:6',
        'retype_password' => 'required|same:password',
        'email' => 'required|unique:users|email|max:255',
    ];
    $recaptchaRules = [
        'g-recaptcha-response' => 'required|recaptcha',
    ];

    // Set session if recaptcha is valid
    if (Validator::make($request->all(), $recaptchaRules)->passes()) {
        session(['recaptcha' => true]);
    } 
    // Add recaptcha rules to default rules if failed to get single message bag with all errors
    else {
        $defaultRules = array_merge($defaultRules, $recaptchaRules);
    }

    // Validation
    $this->validate($request, $defaultRules);

    // Database save part here...        

    // Reset recaptcha validity so that the recaptcha is displayed on the next submission
    session(['recaptcha' => false]);

    return redirect()->route('register')->with('info', 'Success!');
}
```

Only output the Recaptcha field it if hasn't already been validated.

```
@unless (session('recaptcha'))
    {{ Recaptcha::render() }}
@endunless
```

Comment: It has a little bit of bug. However, I got the idea, and this is great!

Comment: I just spotted my mistake with the `$this->validate()` call, but glad you got it sorted.